# How can I use wicket i18n features without a running wicket application

Tags: java, internationalization, wicket

Given:

- a wicket application with fully configured `*.properties` files for multiple languages

Required:

- a batch application should also be able to get a localized value, using key and locale, with locale fallbacks and so on, behaving just like wicket normally does this.

Tried so far:

- `WicketApplication.get().getResourceSettings().getLocalizer()` - does not work, as no wicket application is available in the context of batch application.

Comment: Doesn't Wicket just use the standard [ResourceBundles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)?

Comment: This covers only part of what I want: there should also be a fallback like "de_De -> de -> en" or something like this. I could implement this myself, but I am not a fan of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See org.apache.wicket.resource.loader.ComponentStringResourceLoader#loadStringResource(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String, java.util.Locale, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) [1]. This is where the magic happens.

1. https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/792a0a4138aad61dfe63c8bace96648878767003/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/resource/loader/ComponentStringResourceLoader.java#L131-L151